# Find row name of a Table given max value

Tags: r, row-number

I have a table, `tble` from a dataframe, `df`as below:

```
tble<-table(df$eye_color)
```

So it produces values as follows:

```
tble
    Brown        Black      Green      Blue
     7          10          2           1
```

I want to define a variable that returns the  row name with the max value in the table. For this example, it would be Black.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange, I did not find a duplicate when I search "[r] max of a table". But I remember seeing something similar.

```
names(tble)[which.max(tble)]
```